# cannot effect image with css - need to move up with a neg. margin

Tags: css, image, wordpress, margin

This is a really odd one. I cannot seem to affect this one image via css at all.  Tried adding a class specifically for the image and also writing css to affect just the image, but zip.  It won't budge. The only thing that made it move was setting the neg. margin on the actual image, and there it only moved up about **40px** and wouldn't go any further (taken that off since then). The image in question is the "imagine" tab **(wp-image-39)** on this page:http://circore.com/haute/.  The bits of css I've left are:

```
img.wp-image-39
{
margin-top:-120px;
background:#ff0000;
}
.toptab
{
margin-top:-120px;
background:#ff0000;
}
```

I've also tried affecting all images in the content area and a bunch of other things.  The red background is just so I can see if something worked.  Argh!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I guess you have *{magrin:0 !important} dirrective in your CSS. Gimme the URl of your page and I will tell you for sure.

Comment: What browsers are you testing in?

Comment: Firefox for browser.  Nope, only !important tags are for print.  The url http://circore.com/haute/.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to put styles on the image, why not put styles on the containing `div`?

`.toptab { margin-top: -50px; }`

Would that suit your needs?

Comment: I've got .toptab { margin-top: -120px; } in there and it doesn't affect the image at all. Nothing seems to budge this image, but just THIS one image. position:absolute does nothing either.  I'm just so baffled.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided (http://circore.com/haute/) I can see there aren't any styles being applied to the `.toptab` element (you can verify that by doing "Inspect Element" with Firebug or Chrome/Safari Developer Tools). Maybe the styles you think you're applying just aren't being picked up?

Comment: That is extra-odd, b/c I'm also using firebug and web developer in firefox. This stuff is at the very end of style.css so I can find it easily.  Other css styles I've changed have shown up just fine too.

Comment: Looking at your `style.css` file, @Dick Laurent is correct -- those styles are being included into your `@media print` styles, so wouldn't show up in the web view (and your print styles do not contain a closing `}`). Move them before the print styles.

Comment: Yes, that worked!  It's telling me I don't need an additional } but everything snapped into place.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would set `position: absolute` for the image. Then you will be able to move it freely with margins relative to its inline position.

Comment: Elements nested in each other should appear inside each other. If the markup is fix your only way is a woraround. If not, then put the image outside of the container, if you want to display it outside.

Answer (score 1):

The last 3 classes of your CSS

```
#text-4
{
font-size:11px;
line-height: 15px;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
}

img.wp-image-39
{
margin-top:-120px;
background:#ff0000;
}
.toptab
{
margin-top:-120px;
background:#ff0000;
}
```

are inside @media print { which is actually not closed.

Put a closing bracket before #text-4 or wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin-top:-120px;">
```

Inline CSS would work also on the div that wraps around the . Hope this helps.